# If $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous then it is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-continuity

I have an exercise in my textbook:

[image]

The first one I try to prove by contrapositive:

Suppose $f$ is not bounded. Then $\forall M \in \Bbb R : |f(x)| \gt M \text{ },\forall x \in X$

$\Rightarrow f(x) \gt M $ or $f(x) \lt -M$

Hence $\forall \epsilon \text{ }\exists \delta \leq |b-a| : |x-y| \lt \delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)| \gt \epsilon$ since

$$|f(x)| \gt M \Leftrightarrow f(x) \gt M \text{ or } f(x) \lt -M$$

$\Rightarrow f(x) \gt \epsilon + f(y) \text{ or } f(x) \lt -\epsilon-f(y)$

$\Leftrightarrow |f(x) -f(y)| \gt \epsilon$

Hence, by definition, $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

I think I'm doing something wrong since in the following task I observe that the function $g(x) =x$, $\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is not bounded but it is uniformly continuous.

(also, $g(x)= \text{sin}(x)$ is uniformly continuous, right?)

Comment: This is not correct. The definition of unbounded is for all $M>0$, there exists $x$ such that $|f(x)|>M$. Moreover, $|f(x)|>M$ means $f(x)>M$ or $f(x)<-M$. It can't be both.

Comment: Regarding your examples, the exercise states that $f$ is defined on a bounded interval, $(a, b)$. Uniformly continuous functions functions are bounded on compact subsets of their domains.

Comment: Note the difference between $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb R$ and $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: $(a,b)$ is not compact.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC * bounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you need to brush up on negations.

**Bounded:** There exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

**Negation:** For all $M>0$, there exists $x\in(a,b)$ such that $|f(x)|>M$.

**Uniformly continuous:** For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

**Negation:** There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$, there exists $x,y$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, but $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq \epsilon$.

In this problem, I don't see much value from using a proof by contradiction. For the direct proof, here are some hints. (Uniformly) continuous functions are bounded on closed intervals. Therefore, for any small $\delta>0$, we have  $f$ is bounded on $[a+\delta,b-\delta]$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be fixed. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in(a,b)$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Consider the interval $(a,a+\delta]$. Restrict $\delta$ so that $(a,a+\delta]\subset (a,b)$ and $[b-\delta,b)\subset (a,b)$. Fix $y\in (a,a+\delta]$. Then what can you say about $f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,a+\delta]$? Apply a similar argument on $[b-\delta,b)$. You will get three bounds, on the intervals $(a,a+\delta],\, [a+\delta,b-\delta],\, [b-\delta,b)$ respectively.

Comment: How would you bound the function for $(a,a+\delta]$?

Comment: Take any fixed $y\in (a,a+\delta]$. Then for all $x\in (a,a+\delta]$, we have $|x-y|<\delta$ so $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon \implies -\epsilon+f(y)<f(x)<\epsilon+f(y)$.

Comment: Lev.You have for fixed $y \in (a,a+\delta] $: $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon,$ or $-\epsilon +f(y) <f(x)<f(y)+\epsilon$, where $x \in (a,a+\delta].$

Comment: @PeterSzilas and zugzug Ah! Thanks

Comment: @Lev Bahn. :):)

Comment: "Then what can you say about $f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,a+\delta]$?" That $f(x) \lt \epsilon +f(y)$ for all $x \in (a,a+\delta]$?

Comment: Bounded means bounded above and below...

Comment: Yes, sorry. So $|f(x)| \lt \epsilon + f(y)$ for all $ x \in (a, a+ \delta]$?

Comment: No. Here's what you want: $f(x)<\epsilon + f(y)\leq |\epsilon + f(y)|\leq \max\{|\epsilon+f(y)|,|-\epsilon+f(y)|\}$. Similarly, $f(x)>-\epsilon + f(y)\geq -|-\epsilon + f(y)|\geq -\max\{|\epsilon+f(y)|,|-\epsilon+f(y)|\}$. Therefore, if you are looking for a number $M_1$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M_1$, choose $M_1=\max\{|\epsilon+f(y)|,|-\epsilon+f(y)|\}$.

Comment: @zugzug oh, okay. Cheers!

Comment: Do we have to consider all possible combinations of x and y in those 3 intervals. Or is it sufficient to just fix y and consider x in each interval?